# Google Analytics disappearing visitors

Tags: google-analytics

Okay this one is just blowing my mind. The number of visitors for the day went down.

At 5am I check the analytics and it says today:  (Monday, January 6th, 2014 visits:33)

Noon I check the analytics and it says today:  (Monday, January 6th, 2014 visits:7)

Just to make it clear yesterday was and still is 6 and the prior day was and still is 15. This means that the visitors were there, and were 'erased'.

How in the world is that possible? Time Machines? Bot Adjustments?

Comment: My guess is that it's a timezone thing. If your page uses utc, or any other non-local to you timezone, "midnight" might not be your local time, at which point the pageviews are reset.

Comment: but wouldn't they be added to the previous day, and/or wouldn't that mean that I could potentially be losing visitor data every day

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question. here's some info on timezone settings in google analytics : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en are you settings set to your local timezone?

Comment: I guess a better way to understand this is, does it say Jan 6th : 7 visitors, or does it say "Today" : 7 visitors? Analytics has changed pretty dramatically since the last time I used it.

Comment: edited the Q to make it more clear that it's as if visitors were erased. Checked out the timezone issue, and it's all set the same

Comment: it might be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925944/google-analytics-unique-visitors-dropped-in-count?rq=1

Comment: I checked that one and it's about the 'unique visitors' number not the number on the graph itself. If it was that issue, then the two previous days would change in some way (they didn't)

Answer (score 0):

A lone visitor was browsing through the website, this caused the page-views to go way up. In the wee am hours I didn't catch that I was looking at page-views instead of Unique visits. Even now the page-views is way above the number of uniques. This is due to some lone visitor browsing through everything repeatedly (good news I guess).